# Unable to create an entry in the database using create function from the controller

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models - CallDetail and Agent. agents table uses foreign key from call_details table.

The schema is pasted below.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170824171227) do

  create_table "agents", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "agent_id"
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "CallDetail_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["CallDetail_id"], name: "index_agents_on_CallDetail_id"
  end

  create_table "call_details", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "call_id"
    t.string "word"
    t.float "start_time"
    t.float "end_time"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

In the above database schema, in addition to the attributes shown rails by default creates CallDetail ID and Agent ID attributes.

My Agents controller create function looks like the following

```
def create
    @agent = Agent.new(agent_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @agent.save
        format.html { redirect_to @agent, notice: 'Agent was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @agent }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @agent.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

My models are given below

```
class CallDetail < ApplicationRecord
end
class Agent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :CallDetail
end
```

When I open localhost:3000/agents and try to create a new entry in the database the following error is shown.

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.CallDetails: INSERT INTO "agents" ("agent_id", "name", "CallDetail_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhaMZ.png)

I am new to rails. What am I doing incorrectly here? Please help.

Comment: is your app connected to the db and have those tables ? check it from `rails console`, then enter `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables`

Comment: yes it seems to be connected, the output in the console reads => ["schema_migrations", "ar_internal_metadata", "call_details", "agents"] @sa77

Comment: How did you create the association between agents and call_details?

Comment: @hashrocket I used the following generate scaffold command to create association between CallDetail and Agent  :   rails g scaffold Agent agent_id:integer name:string CallDetail:references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails uses inflections to change the names of models (among other things). You are incorrectly referencing CallDetail. When referencing CallDetail, you should use snake_case, not CamelCase. You are calling CallDetail where you should be calling call_detail.

Notice in your schema file that CallDetail got converted to call_details. This is one of the ways Rails uses inflections. You can read about inflections [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html).

Comment: yes using snake_case works. rails is super sensitive with conventions. i am just wondering why did it allow me to create a wrong reference to begin with. anyhow thanks a lot @hashrocket.